# How to obtain a specified set of coefficients of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j$ between $1$ and $n$. I have the following polynomial and the corresponding expansion (correct me if I am wrong):

$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+ \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} x_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \prod_{k \in \sigma_i} \sum_{j=1}^n b_{kj} x_j$,

where $\sigma_i$ are all subsets of the set of natural numbers from $1$ to $n$.

My first problem is to obtain all $2^n$ monomials from the mentioned polynomial that do not contain any powers of the variables, that is all coefficients $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ of

$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+ \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} x_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \alpha_i \prod_{j \in \sigma_i} x_j +$ terms with powers of $x_j$.

The second task is to check whether it is possible to factor the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \alpha_i \prod_{j \in \sigma_i} x_j$ back into a product of $n$ factors for the specific $\alpha_i$ obtained from the previous step.

Any help would be highly appreciated.